# Readable submodule status information in git

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a script that checks out a repo, checks out the submodules, then prints some info about the submodules so that the user knows which tags/branches they are dealing with.

The output on my own workstation looks like this:

```
        Entering 'SubModuleA', 
        * feature/some_feature_branch,
        Branch is, 
        feature/some_feature_branch,
        Tag is, 
        undefined, 
        Entering 'SubModuleB'
        * (detached from 1.1.9)
        Branch is
        HEAD
        Tag is
        1.1.9^0
```

In this example, the main repo is pointing a feature branch of Submodule A and a tag of Submodule B.

But when I use ansible to run this code on other workstations or VMs, the output looks different:

```
        Entering 'SubModuleA', 
        * (detached from 1234abcd), 
        Branch is, 
        HEAD, 
        Tag is, 
        undefined, 
        Entering 'SubModuleB'
        * (detached from a1b23c4d)
        Branch is
        HEAD
        Tag is
        1.1.9^0
```

The code looks like this:

```
 git submodule foreach 'git branch | grep \* ; echo Branch is && git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD ;  echo Tag is && git name-rev --tags --name-only $(git rev-parse HEAD) '
```

It's a bit of a hodge-podge of other examples I've found to get this kind of info, but I'm having trouble finding something that is consistent.

The command that is immediately before the status check in the playbook is

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting different results. Is there anything that will reliably print the branch name and tag name of a submodule consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the source of your confusion is that the only information git stores with respect to the state of a submodule is the commit ID.  Consider an existing repository with multiple branches, say, this one:

- https://github.com/githubtraining/hellogitworld.git

Clone it:

```
$ git https://github.com/githubtraining/hellogitworld.git
$ cd hellogitworld
```

Now, get the commit ID of a named branch (say, 'master'):

```
$ git rev-parse master
ef7bebf8bdb1919d947afe46ab4b2fb4278039b3
```

Now, check out that commit ID:

```
$ git checkout ef7bebf8bdb1919d947afe46ab4b2fb4278039b3
```

And run `git status`:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached at ef7bebf
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

As you can see, even though you have checked out a commit ID that
corresponds to a named branch, `git` doesn't know that (because you
located the commit id directly, rather than by looking it up via the
name).

This is exactly what happens if you clone a repository that contains
submodules.  The submodules are checked out *by commit id*, not by
any named branch.  This is actually a critical feature: it ensures
that you always get the same commit even if the branch advances in the
linked repository.

You can use the `git describe` command to get the name of the
branch in this case.  For example:

```
$ git describe --all
heads/master
```

The `--all` flag is required in order to get `git describe` to
consider branch names as well as tags.

Comment: Also keep in mind that a commit can be on multiple branches, if it existed before a new branch was created. So you can't really think in terms of what branch a parent project points to. It points to a commit, which may be on several branches.

Comment: Nice! This works for almost everything! There's still two submodules that print something like `heads/develop-5-a244b796`, everything else is `tags/SomeTag` or `remotes/origin/feature/SomeFeature`.